# add datetime values to previous datetime values

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

How can I add timedate to already timedate or timespan value recursively?

I've tried this but it gives me error:

> 'A local variable named 'total' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'total, which is already
>   in used in a 'parent or current' scope  to denote something else'

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = 0;
            string path = @"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                string[] lines = new String[500]; 

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan total = now - now;
                int temp=0;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lines[a] = line;
                    a++;

                }

                while (temp < a)
                {

                    TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[temp+1]) - Convert.ToDateTime(lines[temp]);
                    TimeSpan total = total + difference; // <----ERROR HERE
                    Console.WriteLine(total);
                    Console.WriteLine(difference);
                    temp = temp + 2;
                }

            }
        }
```

Also is there any better way to set datetime value to zero so that I can add values recursively?

Answer (score 3):

You have defined 'total' twice in your method. Have you tried removing 'TimeSpan' from the second definition?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, since you already have a variable with the same name, replace with some other variable name,

```
 TimeSpan newTotal = total + difference;
 Console.WriteLine(newTotal);
```

better way is to remove the TimeSpan before total so you do not have to repeat ,

```
  total = total + difference; 
  Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says , the variable is already defined. Work on the same variable, or declare a new one with other name:

```
total = total + difference;
```

or

```
TimeSpan total2 = total + difference;
```